# Parent buying Minecraft (Windows 10) for child

Tags: windows-10, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm a lifelong Windows user but I've never signed in with a Microsoft Account or made any Store purchases, so please bear with me.

My child has got into playing the copy of Minecraft that magically appeared on my Windows 10 laptop, and I am considering paying for the full version.

I'm pretty confused about the relationship between the purchased game and  Microsoft Accounts / Microsoft Store / Minecraft User profiles.

If I register a Microsoft account for myself and log into the Store app with that then buy Minecraft, will my child then need to be logged in as me in order to play it? Would it be possible for me to set up some parental restrictions in that scenario? Or is it expected that the child has a Microsoft account of their own, and would the original purchase then have to be through that account?

Comment: If you're new to Minecraft, I recommend checking out the original Minecraft also (or instead), now called "Java edition". It has lots more features and a more stable code base, less serious issues, no chat filter and so on. But I would recommend playing the 1.12.2 version of it, because all later versions have their own issues, which will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: @stovroz I agree with Mkalafut and Fabian Röling, the java version is the one you should get him. the microsoft version with the free trial is a trick by microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

You may have an easier time buying the [Java Edition](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/) and creating an account there.  Your question wasn't too clear on whether or not you two share a laptop or necessarily want to share an account, but in either case it's pretty simple to make an account for both of you here.

In this case you create a Mojang account and it's completely independent of a Microsoft account (as your comments mentioned you'd like to avoid).

This takes Microsoft out of the equation entirely **but** it doesn't allow for you to create a "child" account necessarily or create parental controls.  But in this case you just set up an account and you're ready to roll.

Plus the Java edition has the added bonus of much more customization compared to the Windows edition (which charges for things you can get and do for free in the Java edition).

Comment: Unfortunately this suggestion is no more valid: on 21st october 2020 official Minecraft site announced the migration from Mojang accounts to Microsoft accounts mandatory for all Minecraft Java Edition users. See https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/article/java-edition-moving-house

Answer (score 2):

[You can buy games as gifts](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/digitalgiftgames). During your purchase, you can enter the email address or 'gamertag' of the recipient, and after the payment, they will receive a link to accept the game and add it to their account.

In your case, it's easier to initially set up your child's account on Windows 10 through your own account, after which [you can set parental control on theirs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12439/microsoft-account-set-content-restrictions-on-windows-10-and-xbox-one), and more easily buy them products. If they already have an account, you're going to need access to it to set the parental control.
[Here](https://www.netnanny.com/blog/how-to-set-parental-controls-for-windows-10/)'s a guide to do so - I copied the instructions verbatim:

- Open Windows settings and select 'Accounts'.
- Select 'Family & Other People' from the left-hand menu.
- Click on 'Add a Family Member'.
- Select 'Add a Child'.
- Enter the email address of their Microsoft Account below if you have it.
- If your child already has a Microsoft account, click through the remainder of this dialogue. If not, click 'The person I want to add doesn’t have an email address', and set up a new Microsoft account.
- After this, you can start adjusting the child's account limitations to your liking.

Comment: Am I supposed to do all this before buying the game? And then buy the game as a gift for the child account? And then the child must use their account to login to the Windows machine before playing?

Comment: You can also buy the game through your kids account. And taking those steps will take ten minutes *if* you have to set up a new account, five if not.

Comment: I don't really want my child having an account with Microsoft at all if it can be avoided, I just want to buy the game and let them have their own profile in it.

Comment: You can let your child play through your account, or make a new temporary one for the situation. I'm not sure how much information you'll need for that, but not a lot, I guess. But, as mentioned, you can buy a standalone Java Minecraft for Windows, too. Install it on Windows, allow all users to use it, and let your kid play through his/her Windows profile (which doesn't need any kind of registration, since I never tied my Windows 10 installation to an account). You don't have a lot of control over content within Minecraft anyway, so the parental control wouldn't have helped a lot for MC itself

Comment: On the screen where the "Add a family member" button is, you can instead choose "Add someone else to this PC" then click "I don't have this person's sign-in information" followed by "Add a user without a Microsoft Account"

Comment: Worth mentioning that the main benefit of the Microsoft parental features in Minecraft is probably the ability to prevent them from playing online with strangers. That said, I don't think you can play online without an account so the point is probably moot. If they have friends with realms they want to play with you should be able to set it up so that your child can play on those realms but not in the public servers with strangers.

Comment: @CasualViking Unfortunately it's not possible to use the parental and privacy controls to limit the child to specific private realms :-( I wish it was. Parental controls unfortunately aren't that granular. Blocking access to online public servers, also blocks access to all private realms.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant that it's possible to allow the child to use realms without allowing them to use servers. Although there are some realms that allow anyone to join, realms are much more limited in the number of users that can be online at one time (I believe 20 is the maximum) whereas servers can have thousands of people on at once.

Comment: @CasualViking Are you sure this is possible? Have you actually been able to do it? I haven't found any way to allow realms while blocking other servers.

Comment: @user1751825 It has been so long since I looked that I don't remember how (my previous comment was a year ago), but I believe I found a way to do this and considered it for my nephew's account.

Comment: @CasualViking Perhaps it's a feature they used to support, but don't anymore. From my research such a setup is not possible, at least not without serious hacking, blocking IP's and/or ports etc. Enabling realms also enables online servers. The parental controls and xbox privacy settings don't seem to have any way to distinguish between public servers and private realms. I've just been switching on and off online games to control this. It's very annoying. I suspect Microsoft/Mojang don't want to allow this capability as it may impact revenue for their official server partners.

Comment: Here there is also a reply from a Microsoft Agent : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_family/allow-child-to-play-minecraft-with-family-win10/b3b6a092-0518-4d99-958b-b221003009e7

Answer (score 0):

If you buy the full game from the store, your child should also be able to play it when logged in to the laptop with his profile.

I'd recommend you register a Windows account for yourself and your child, and then setup a family profile. With this you will have easy control over how long he can play etc. You'll also need to setup an XBox Gamer profile with the same account. It's all fairly straighforward.

The Windows version is very nicely integrated with the whole XBox ecosystem. I believe the Windows 10 Minecraft license will also cover the XBox console, if you ever get one of those.

Comment: could you back that up with a source of some sort? While I heard this now and then, I haven't seen a roadmap from Microsoft itself on this. There is still a very large playerbase that adheres to the Java-version for reasons like modding.

Comment: I can't find a source for this, so I've removed this statement. There doesn't seem to have been any official word from Microsoft about when it will happen. Supporting two completely different code-bases just doesn't make sense long term.

Answer (score -1):

I set up something like this for my nephew.

First, create an account for yourself.

Then, create an account with parental controls for your kid with yourself as the guardian.

Your kid can use this account to log in to Minecraft Bedrock regardless of device (so they can use the pc, but for example, my nephew uses tablet, I use mobile and XBox One and they're all compatible with eachother) but will not be able to join multiplayer servers or realms unless you give them permission to do so.

Not sure of you would need to buy the game for your kid, or in their name, or just buy it on the computer you'll be using it on.

Edit: I was going to expand these instructions, but you can just follow Joachim's answer for fuller instructions.